# Deep learning Keras model CTC_Loss gives loss = infinity

Tags: python-3.x, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, recurrent-neural-network

i've a CRNN model for text recognition, it was published on Github, trained on english language,

Now i'm doing the same thing using this algorithm but for arabic.

My ctc function is:

```
def ctc_lambda_func(args):
        y_pred, labels, input_length, label_length = args
        # the 2 is critical here since the first couple outputs of the RNN
        # tend to be garbage:
        y_pred = y_pred[:, 2:, :]
        return K.ctc_batch_cost(labels, y_pred, input_length, label_length)
```

My Model is:

```
def get_Model(training):

        img_w = 128
        img_h = 64


        # Network parameters
        conv_filters = 16
        kernel_size = (3, 3)
        pool_size = 2
        time_dense_size = 32
        rnn_size = 128


        if K.image_data_format() == 'channels_first':
            input_shape = (1, img_w, img_h)
        else:
            input_shape = (img_w, img_h, 1)
        # Initialising the CNN
        act = 'relu'
        input_data = Input(name='the_input', shape=input_shape, dtype='float32')
        inner = Conv2D(conv_filters, kernel_size, padding='same',
                           activation=act, kernel_initializer='he_normal',
                           name='conv1')(input_data)
        inner = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(pool_size, pool_size), name='max1')(inner)
        inner = Conv2D(conv_filters, kernel_size, padding='same',
                           activation=act, kernel_initializer='he_normal',
                           name='conv2')(inner)
        inner = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(pool_size, pool_size), name='max2')(inner)

        conv_to_rnn_dims = (img_w // (pool_size ** 2), (img_h // (pool_size ** 2)) * conv_filters)
        inner = Reshape(target_shape=conv_to_rnn_dims, name='reshape')(inner)

            # cuts down input size going into RNN:
        inner = Dense(time_dense_size, activation=act, name='dense1')(inner)

            # Two layers of bidirectional GRUs
            # GRU seems to work as well, if not better than LSTM:
        gru_1 = GRU(rnn_size, return_sequences=True, kernel_initializer='he_normal', name='gru1')(inner)
        gru_1b = GRU(rnn_size, return_sequences=True, go_backwards=True, kernel_initializer='he_normal', name='gru1_b')(inner)
        gru1_merged = add([gru_1, gru_1b])
        gru_2 = GRU(rnn_size, return_sequences=True, kernel_initializer='he_normal', name='gru2')(gru1_merged)
        gru_2b = GRU(rnn_size, return_sequences=True, go_backwards=True, kernel_initializer='he_normal', name='gru2_b')(gru1_merged)

            # transforms RNN output to character activations:
        inner = Dense(num_classes+1, kernel_initializer='he_normal',
                          name='dense2')(concatenate([gru_2, gru_2b]))
        y_pred = Activation('softmax', name='softmax')(inner)
        Model(inputs=input_data, outputs=y_pred).summary()

        labels = Input(name='the_labels', shape=[30], dtype='float32')
        input_length = Input(name='input_length', shape=[1], dtype='int64')
        label_length = Input(name='label_length', shape=[1], dtype='int64')
            # Keras doesn't currently support loss funcs with extra parameters
            # so CTC loss is implemented in a lambda layer
        loss_out = Lambda(ctc_lambda_func, output_shape=(1,), name='ctc')([y_pred, labels, input_length, label_length])

            # clipnorm seems to speeds up convergence



            # the loss calc occurs elsewhere, so use a dummy lambda func for the loss

        if training:
            return Model(inputs=[input_data, labels, input_length, label_length], outputs=loss_out)

            return Model(inputs=[input_data], outputs=y_pred)
```

Then i compile it with SGD optimizer (Tried SGD,adam)

```
sgd = SGD(lr=0.0000002, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True, clipnorm=5)
model.compile(loss={'ctc': lambda y_true, y_pred: y_pred}, optimizer=sgd)
```

Then i fit the model with my training set (Images of words up to 30 characters) into (sequence of labels of 30

```
model.fit_generator(generator=tiger_train.next_batch(),
                steps_per_epoch=int(tiger_train.n / batch_size),
                epochs=30,
                callbacks=[checkpoint],
                validation_data=tiger_val.next_batch(),
                validation_steps=int(tiger_val.n / val_batch_size))
```

Once it starts, it give me loss = inf, after many searches, i didn't find any similar problem.

So my questions is, how can i solve this, what can make a ctc_loss compute an infinite cost?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem, it was dimensions problem,

For `R-CNN OCR` using `CTC layer`, if you are detecting a sequence with `length n`, you should have an image with at least a width of `(2*n-1)`. The more the better till you reach the best image/timesteps ratio to let the `CTC layer` able to recognize the letter correctly. If image with is less than `(2*n-1)`, it will give a nan loss.

Answer (score 0):

This error is happened when image text have two equal characters in the same sequence e.g happen --> pp.  for so that you can remove data that has this characteristic.